# I could not add sp_BlitzIndex store procedure to SQL Server 2014 version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sp-blitzindex

I cannot successfully add the sp_BlitzIndex store procedure for Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU3-GDR) and earlier versions. I think there is something related to the version. Because I was able to add it for SQL Server 2022 version. Can you help me ?

PS: I don't know the exact version. I downloaded it as First Responder Kit a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a known bug](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/3452). The pull request found [here](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/pull/3453) claims to have a fix. Said fix seems reasonable to my eyes. Either wait on it getting merged or use the code from the PR and you should be able to install it.

Also,

> PS: I don't know the exact version.

It is very easy to find the version in the code of the version that you have downloaded. Just open it up and look.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the script and I added the updated sp_BlitzIndex store procedure. When ı run the store procedure, ı received the below error.

Do you have any idea?

Starting run. sp_BlitzIndex(TM) v8.19 - February 22, 2024
Create temp tables.
Adding UQ index on #IndexSanity (database_id, object_id, index_id)
Number of databases to examine: 1
Checking partition counts to exclude databases with over 100 partitions
Starting loop through databases

master
starting at 2024-03-13 12:08:15
Inserting data into #IndexColumns for clustered indexes and heaps
Inserting data into #IndexColumns for nonclustered indexes
Inserting data into #IndexSanity
Checking partition count
Preferring non-2012 syntax with LEFT JOIN to sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats
Inserting data into #IndexPartitionSanity
Failure populating temp tables.
Last @dsql:
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(19) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 121)
RAISERROR (N'start getting data into #dm_db_partition_stats_etc at (null)',0,1, @d) WITH NOWAIT;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
INSERT INTO #dm_db_partition_stats_etc
(
database_id, object_id, sname, index_id, partition_number, partition_id, row_count, reserved_MB, reserved_LOB_MB, reserved_row_overflow_MB, lock_escalation_desc, data_compression_desc
)
SELECT  1 AS database_id,
ps.object_id,
s.name as sname,
ps.index_id,
ps.partition_number,
ps.partition_id,
ps.row_count,
ps.reserved_page_count * 8. / 1024. AS reserved_MB,
ps.lob_reserved_page_count * 8. / 1024. AS reserved_LOB_MB,
ps.row_overflow_reserved_page_count * 8. / 1024. AS reserved_row_overflow_MB,
le.lock_escalation_desc,
par.data_compression_desc

```
        FROM    [master].sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps  
                JOIN [master].sys.partitions AS par on ps.partition_id=par.partition_id
                JOIN [master].sys.objects AS so ON ps.object_id = so.object_id
                           AND so.is_ms_shipped = 0 /*Exclude objects shipped by Microsoft*/
                           AND so.type <> 'TF' /*Exclude table valued functions*/
                JOIN [master].sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = so.schema_id
                    OUTER APPLY (SELECT st.lock_escalation_desc
                                 FROM [master].sys.tables st
                                 WHERE st.object_id = ps.object_id
                                     AND ps.index_i...
```

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzIndex, Line 2369
master database failed to process. Invalid column name 'hobt_id'.